# How can I redirect a request file to real folder with htaccess?

Tags: html, css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**What I have**

I have created a folder called "**r**" in my server and I have put all css, js and images in it, with respective subfolders.

E.g.:

```
/
|public_html
           |r
             |styles
             |js
             |img
```

**What I want**

Web pages and stylesheets, who send a call for rescuing files, must have a pattern as: "resources/(.+)".

E.g.

In html document `<script src="resources/js/jquery.js"></script>`

In css document `@import url('resources/css/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css');`

**What I did**

I tried to set the .htaccess file in public_html (because the server requires to publish the web site in it) with Alias and AliasMatch but the server catched an internal error.

Then I tried with RewriteRule using both absolute and relative path like below:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^resources/(.*)$ r/$1
```

**What happen in real**

It works half and half!

The requests from root domain (www.example.com) are loaded correctly, but from stylesheet where loaded.

E.g.

index.html requests `resources/styles/home.css` and works;

home.css requests `resource/img/bg.png` and doesn't work.

In web inspector, the request is shown `http://www.example.com/resources/styles/resources/img/bg.png`
and it's look like there was no RewriteRule.

**Final**

How can I fix this problem? And, please, explain step-by-step the answer so I can better understand my mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rewrite rule is working just fine. The problem is that you're using relative paths. `resources/styles/home.css` relative to `www.example.com` is `www.example.com/resources/styles/home.css`. However, `resource/img/bg.png` relative to `www.example.com/resources/styles/home.css` is `www.example.com/resources/styles/resources/img/bg.png`. This path resolution is happening in the browser, your rewrite rules have absolutely nothing to do with it.

Fix your CSS file and other relative references to point to the correct files. In your CSS file you should point to `../img/bg.png` or `/resource/img/bg.png`.

Comment: Thank you guy! I solved this issue pointing resources in CSS to `../ect`, this makes sense because every file that a web page needs to load it is only in **r** folder.